# Detect silence in a playing MP3 with Javascript

Tags: html, audio

I want to use HTML5 to play an MP3 file.

When there is, let's say 60 seconds of silence, or maybe 10% of the average sound level, I want to call a Javascript function.

Compatibility: Webkit only. Here are some examples of Chrome's audio API
http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html